How can I compare a value in one column to all values that are BEFORE it in another column to find the number of unique values that are less than?
This is my DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [100, 100, 105, 106, 106, 107, 108, 109],
        'b': [99, 100, 110, 107, 100, 110, 120, 106],
    }
)

Expected output is creating column x:
     a    b    x
0  100   99    0
1  100  100    1
2  105  110    2
3  106  107    3
4  106  100    1
5  107  110    4
6  108  120    5
7  109  106    3

Logic:
This is somehow an extension to this answer. I explain the logic by examples and I start from row 1:
For row 1, the b column value is 100. Then in order to get x for row 1 this value should be compared with all UNIQUE values in a that are on the same row or before it to find out how many values in a are less than or equal to it. The only unique value that is on the same row or before it is 100, so 1 is chosen for x.
For row 2, there are two unique values in a that are less than or equal to 110 which are 100, 105.
The logic is the same for the rest of rows.
This is my attempt based on the linked answer but it does not work:
t = df.a.unique()
m1 = np.arange(len(t))[:,None] >= np.arange(len(t))

h = df['b'].to_numpy()
m2 = t <= h[:, None]


IIUC, use numpy broadcasting, tril, and a mask to only keep the unique values:
a = df['a'].mask(df['a'].duplicated()).to_numpy()
b = df['b'].to_numpy()
df['x'] = np.tril(b[:, None]>=a).sum(axis=1)

As a one-liner:
df['x'] = np.tril(df[['b']].to_numpy() >=
                   df['a'].mask(df['a'].duplicated()).to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)

Output:
     a    b  x
0  100   99  0
1  100  100  1
2  105  110  2
3  106  107  3
4  106  100  1
5  107  110  4
6  108  120  5
7  109  106  3

Intermediates:
# a
array([100.,  nan, 105., 106.,  nan, 107., 108., 109.])

# b
array([ 99, 100, 110, 107, 100, 110, 120, 106])

# np.tril(b[:, None]>=a)
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False]])


Thanks a lot. Is it possible to use the same approach for the post for the linked answer? I just want to know.

@AmirX for the linked question I'd probably use numba

For change original solution change t for replace duplicated values to NaNs and for count Trues use sum of both masks:
t = df['a'].mask(df['a'].duplicated()).to_numpy()
m1 = np.arange(len(t))[:,None] >= np.arange(len(t))

h = df['b'].to_numpy()
m2 = h[:, None] >= t

df['x'] = (m1 & m2).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
     a    b  x
0  100   99  0
1  100  100  1
2  105  110  2
3  106  107  3
4  106  100  1
5  107  110  4
6  108  120  5
7  109  106  3


For Huge and Sparse datasets, Use : from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [100, 100, 105, 106, 106, 107, 108, 109],
    'b': [99, 100, 110, 107, 100, 110, 120, 106],
})

a= df['a'].mask(df['a'].duplicated()).to_numpy()
b= df['b'].to_numpy()

sparse_b  = csr_matrix(b[:,None])

comparison = sparse_b >= a
comparison = csr_matrix(comparison)

tril_indices = (rows,cols) = np.tril_indices(len(b))

tril_row_indices = tril_indices[0]

lower_tril_mask = np.ones(len(tril_indices[0]), dtype=bool)

lower_tril_sparse_matrix = csr_matrix((lower_tril_mask,tril_indices))

res_matrix = comparison.multiply(lower_tril_sparse_matrix)

res =  res_matrix.sum(axis=1).A.flatten()
print(res)#[0 1 2 3 1 4 5 3]

df['res'] =res 
print(df)
'''
    a    b  res
0  100   99    0
1  100  100    1
2  105  110    2
3  106  107    3
4  106  100    1
5  107  110    4
6  108  120    5
7  109  106    3
'''

Normal numpy method 1:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [100, 100, 105, 106, 106, 107, 108, 109],
    'b': [99, 100, 110, 107, 100, 110, 120, 106],
})
a = df['a'].to_numpy()
b = df['b'].to_numpy()
    
# Create a mask to mark duplicates in 'a' as NaN, so they are ignored in comparison
masked_a = np.where(pd.Series(a).duplicated(), np.nan, a)
df['masked_a'] = masked_a    

tril_matrix = np.tril(np.ones((len(b), len(b)), dtype=bool))
 
comparison_matrix = (b[:, None] >= masked_a) & tril_matrix

df['x'] = comparison_matrix.sum(axis=1)
print(df)
'''
    a    b  masked_a  x
0  100   99     100.0  0
1  100  100       NaN  1
2  105  110     105.0  2
3  106  107     106.0  3
4  106  100       NaN  1
5  107  110     107.0  4
6  108  120     108.0  5
7  109  106     109.0  3
'''

Normal Numpy Method 2 :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [100, 100, 105, 106, 106, 107, 108, 109],
    'b': [99, 100, 110, 107, 100, 110, 120, 106],
})

a = df['a'].mask(df['a'].duplicated()).to_numpy()
b = df['b'].to_numpy()

comparison = (b[:,None] >= a)

tril_indices =(row, col) = np.tril_indices(len(b))
print(tril_indices)

lower_tril_mask = np.zeros_like(comparison)
print(lower_tril_mask) 

lower_tril_mask[tril_indices] = True
print(lower_tril_mask) 

res_matrix = comparison*lower_tril_mask
print(res_matrix)

res_matrix_sum = res_matrix.sum(axis=1)
print(res_matrix_sum)#[0 1 2 3 1 4 5 3]

df['res_matrix_sum'] = res_matrix_sum
print(df)
'''
     a    b  res_matrix_sum
0  100   99               0
1  100  100               1
2  105  110               2
3  106  107               3
4  106  100               1
5  107  110               4
6  108  120               5
7  109  106               3
'''


This should be slower than the numpy solutions, but here is a pandas solution:
df.assign(x = [(a.unique() <= b).sum() for a,b in zip(df['a'].expanding(),df['b'])])

